# Rotating Instances on a Curve with Tilt

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, instances

How do you rotate instances along a curve using the Tilt in edit mode?

I have seen a lot of tutorials on aligning instances to the tangent or controlling the tilt from inside the geometry nodes setup but none for this.
This is what I've come up with:
[image]

Afaik it should be aligning the rotation of the instances to the normal of the cruve and then adding the rotation of the tilt. It seems to work as long as the control points on the curve are on the same Z position:

[image]

But, as seen in the first picture, if one of the control handles is higher up then the rotation doesn't align completely with the tilt and I have no idea why.

Is there a way to fix this or do it better than what I have?
I essentially need the cones to behave just like an array that is following the curve and respects the tilt, just without deformation.
The reason I don't use another object following the curve to create the instances is that I need to create some other geometry based on the bottom of the cones afterwards so I think having it all in one node set up would be better.
Alternatively, I don't need that Object instanced specifically, just a cone that can control the top and bottom radius and height in case working with primitives would make it easier

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: Whoops! I think I got the axes wrong initially, but if you want a different alignment, see the [previous rev](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/298810/2).

It seems you want to align $+y$ to *Tangent*, and $+x$ to *Normal*:

[image]

So first align the $+y$ to *Tangent*, then $+x$ to *Normal*:

[image]

[image]

Two other alternatives:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first doesn't work for me for some reason but the second one with the 'Rotate Euler' node works perfectly, Thanks. I'm in blender 3.5.1 so maybe something is different...