# How to align Instances to inside of a curve with Geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'd like to align instances inside of a curve with proper rotation and location.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/298808/rotating-instances-on-a-curve-with-tilt